# bison parser returns error instead of "OK" in my code

Tags: email, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

My Flex code given:

```
%{
#include "parser.tab.h" 
%}

tLOCALPART [A-Za-z0-9\-_]+(([A-Za-z0-9\-_]*|\.?)[A-Za-z0-9\-_])*
tDOMAIN [A-Za-z0-9]+[A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9]+|[A-Za-z0-9]{1}

%%

"Mail" return tMAIL;
"end Mail" return tENDMAIL;
"schedule" return tSCHEDULE;
"end schedule" return tENDSCH;
"send" return  tSEND;
"set" return tSET;
"to" return tTO;
"from" return tFROM;
@ return tAT;
, return tCOMMA;
: return tCOLON;
\( return tLPR;
\) return tRPR;
\[ return tLBR;
\] return tRBR;
[a-zA-Z\_]+[a-zA-Z0-9\_]* return tIDENT;
["][^\"]*["] return tSTRING;
[0-9]{2}"/"[0-9]{2}"/"[0-9]{4} return tDATE;
[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} return tTIME;

{tLOCALPART}"@"({tDOMAIN}"."{tDOMAIN}"."{tDOMAIN}|{tDOMAIN}"."{tDOMAIN}) return tADDRESS;
[ \t\n]+ 
.           return yytext[0];
%%
```

My `parser.y`

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

void yyerror (const char *s)
{
    return;
}

%}

%token tMAIL
%token tENDMAIL
%token tSCHEDULE
%token tENDSCH
%token tSEND
%token tSET
%token tTO
%token tFROM
%token tAT
%token tCOMMA
%token tCOLON
%token tLPR
%token tRPR
%token tLBR
%token tRBR
%token tIDENT
%token tSTRING
%token tADDRESS
%token tDATE
%token tTIME    

%start program

%%

program:
    | mailBlock
    | program mailBlock
    | set
    | set program
;

mailBlock: 
    | tMAIL tFROM tADDRESS tCOLON tENDMAIL
    | tMAIL tFROM tADDRESS tCOLON statements tENDMAIL
;

statements: 
    | set 
    | send  
    | schedule
;

set: tSET tIDENT tLPR tSTRING tRPR
;

send: 
    | tSEND tLBR tSTRING tRBR tTO recipientListExtra
    | tSEND tLBR tIDENT tRBR tTO recipientListExtra
;

sendList: 
    | send
    | send sendList
;

schedule: tSCHEDULE tAT tLBR tDATE tCOMMA tTIME tRBR tCOLON sendList tENDSCH
;


recipientList:
    | recipient
    | recipient tCOMMA recipientList
;

recipientListExtra:      
    | tLBR recipientList tRBR
;

recipient:
    | tLPR tADDRESS tRPR
    | tLPR tSTRING tCOMMA tADDRESS tRPR
    | tLPR tIDENT tCOMMA tADDRESS tRPR
;

%%
int main(){
    if(yyparse()){
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return 1;
    }else{
        printf("OK\n");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and my `test.ms` which returns an `ERROR`. I tried to find the fix but It seemed everything is correct to me

```
set Message ("Welcome to CS305.")

Mail from nermin@mail.com:

    schedule @ [27/10/2021, 07:48]:
        send [Message] to [("Kerem", kerem@mail.com.tr)]
    end schedule
    
    set Message ("Our project is due tomorrow.")
    
    send [Message] to [("Mine", mine@mail.com), 
    (selim@mail.com)]

    
end Mail

Mail from nermin@mail.edu:

end Mail

Mail from serkan@mail.edu:

    set UserName ("There is a meeting at 3pm.")
    
    schedule @ [02/10/2021, 16:00]:
    
        send [MorningMessage] to [(ali@mail.com),
        ("John Doe", emre@mail.com),
        (UserName, ali@mail.com)]
        
        send ["How are you?"] to [("Omer", omer@mail.com)]
        
    end schedule
    
end Mail
```

Comment: You should start by fixing all of those [parsing conflicts](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Algorithm) (8 shift/reduce and 14 reduce/reduce, it says here). Once you do that, you should make some attempt to [debug your parser](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Debugging). If you still can't figure out what's going wrong, update this question with all relevant information or ask a new one.

Comment: A good start might be to remove the accidental [empty productions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Empty-Rules). Try the bison command-line flag `-Wempty` (and make sure to use an explicit `%empty` if you intend an empty production.)